# Using for loop with variables from Designer.cs in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, variables

Hi I'm having a problem,

```
                if (y == 0)
                {
                    if (stjarnorload[y] == 1)
                    {
                        pictureBox6.Image = Properties.Resources.Star_Red;
                        pictureBox7.Image = Properties.Resources.Star_Black;
                        pictureBox8.Image = Properties.Resources.Star_Black;
                        pictureBox9.Image = Properties.Resources.Star_Black;
                        pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resources.Star_Black;
                    }
                }
```

The code: `if(stjarnorload[y] == 1)` in `if(y == 0)` has much code, and when `if(stjarnorload[y] == 2)` it has another code, and same up to 5. Then when `y == 1` I need to do the same thing, but with other variables.

So this is like 30 lines of code if I don't loop it, but you can't use lists with pictureBoxes in Designer.cs someone told me.

Can someone help??

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `MyForm.Designer.cs`?  The file generated by the designer?

You shouldn't really modify it because if you change anything on the form, your changes will be lost.

You can put your changes in the constructor after the call to `InitializeComponent()` in the equivalent `MyForm.cs`.  Does that help?